# Duplicate templates in DOM after browser back click

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I observe a undesired behaviour when it comes to the browser back button and emberjs. If the user clicks on the back button, the page shows twice the rendered handlebar template.

In case that the history is long enough, that "works" even several times and the page gets longer and longer. Somebody seen that issue already (and even solved it)?

My application is currently quite what is shown by Trek at http://trek.github.com/ except that I moved to the new router API of pre4.

Versions

- emberjs 1.0 pre4
- handlebars 1.0 rc1

Comment: I didn't see any issue on github like that. I'm interrested if you can provide a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem. Perhaps something in the routes, or the outlets in the templates.

Comment: There are two cases. I found the reason for the first one: state of controller was stored in the model and was not properly removed/re-initialized therefore.
I am sure the second one is also an issue with the routing between the states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow-up to my own question. There are two issues in my code. One of them I tracked down and share here the solution in case somebody have similar issues.

I had a model definition like

```
App.Member.reopenClass({
  allMembers: [],
  findAll: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.company.com/members',
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this,
      success: function(response){
        response.data.forEach(function(member){
          this.allMembers.addObject(App.Member.create(member))
        }, this)
      }
    })
    return this.allMembers;
  }
});
```

The `allMembers: []` was a reference that retained all members. Upon going back/forth, members for reloaded from the backend and stored again on `allMembers`.

To resolve this one, just define `allMembers` in `findAll`:

```
App.Member.reopenClass({
  findAll: function(){
    var allMembers = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.company.com/members',
      dataType: 'json',
      context: allMembers,
      success: function(response){
        response.data.forEach(function(member){
          this.addObject(App.Member.create(member))
        }, this)
      }
    })
    return allMembers;
  }
});
```

---

There is a second issue that is most probably also related to the way I combined the routes. I will post on it as soon as I have the solution.

**Update, 2013-01-22**

Ok, the second issue has been found as well and emberJS + back button now works perfectly. Again, I would like to quickly summarize what the problem was in case that somebody stumbles over it as well.

The routing definition looked as follows:

```
App.Router.map(function() { 
  this.resource("areas", { path: "/areas" });   
  this.resource("area",  { path: "/areas/:refId" }, function() {
    this.route("new",    { path: "/areas/new" });   
});
```

Furthermore, 'new' and 'area' used the very same view and controller. So, the issue was between the parent route 'area' and its subroute 'new'. The attempt to combine all together, and do some magic within the controller to distinguish which case it is, is just not recommended...

So, solution was:

- use mixins to avoid code duplications (both, 'new' and 'area' use some Google Geocoder stuff)
- create a nice and simple routing as shown below.

And the code would be

```
App.Router.map(function() { 
  this.route("areas",   { path: "/areas" });
  this.route("area",    { path: "/areas/:refId" });
  this.route("newarea", { path: "/area/new"});
});
```

That's it. Enjoy or comment. Always glad to get input from experts